# My contact form send 4 emails

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a contact form on my asp.net website. When we send a message through the form. It sends 4 emails, 3 of them are blank and 1 contains the original information. I want it to send only one email having the right info.
**This is the contact form**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" %>
<div class="styledForm" id="ContactUsForm">
<fieldset class="OneColumn">
<legend>You can also contact us by submitting the below form :</legend>
<div class="FirstRow" onkeypress="return FireDefaultButton(event,SubmitContact);">
        <label>Contact Name<font color="#ff0000">*</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="txtBox" name="ContactName" id="ContactName"  />
    </div>
    <div class="FirstRow" onkeypress="return FireDefaultButton(event,SubmitContact);">
        <label>Contact E-mail<font color="#ff0000">*</font></label>
        <input type="text" class="txtBox" name="ContactEmail" id="ContactEmail"  />
    </div>
    <div class="FirstRow">
        <label style="height:85px">Message<font color="#ff0000">*</font></label>
        <textarea class="txtBox" rows="5" cols="30" name="ContactMessage" id="ContactMessage">   </textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="FirstRow">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <a href="#" class="MaroonButton AllFiveRounded" title="Submit" onclick="return SubmitContact();">Send Message</a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</fieldset>
</div>
```

**Here is the SubmitCOntact function**

```
function SubmitContact() {
    ClearValidations();
    $("#ContactName").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter your Name." } });
    $("#ContactEmail").rules("add", { required: true, email: true, messages: { required: "Please enter your Email Address.", email: "Invalid e-mail address!! Please try user@domain.com." } });
    $("#ContactMessage").rules("add", { required: true, messages: { required: "Please enter your message." } });
    if (FormValidator.form()) {
        SubmitFormInIframe("ContactUsForm", function (data) {
            ShowResult(data, function () {
                $("#ContactUsForm input, #ContactUsForm textarea").val("");
                DisableOverlay();
            }, function () {
                DisableOverlay();
            });
        });
    } else { ShowDialog(Errors, "Error"); }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: You didn't show the code that's actually sending the code. Perhaps that's relevant?

Comment: Additionally, questions asking for debugging help, must provide the **minimal** code required to reproduce the problem (also known as [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) **in the question**. Please take a [tour] and read the [help/on-topic]

Comment: `onKeyPress="..."` sounds strange. Send an email on every keypress?

Comment: @mason here is the code from the utility.cs that actually sends the message i guess. http://pastebin.com/djRX0h3G
Its a bit lengthy but i hope you may see whats wrong? The code may be repeated that is sends 4 mails?

Comment: @UmarSindhu Do not put code in a link to a pastebin. All relevant code must be in the question itself. By the way, did you check if the "onKeyPress" thing that Thomas pointed out was behaving as you expected?

Comment: @mason I'm sorry I'm new here. It won't happen next time.
Yeah i did removed "onkeypress" but it didn't make a difference.